# Orchard Core - Override UserMenuItems-Profile

Tags: razor, orchardcms, orchard-modules

Orchard Core contains `UserMenuItems` views which are templates for the user profile dropdown shown below. There are various, with conditional checks to display based on user permissions.

[image]

I am trying to override this, as I want the `UserMenuItems-Profile` option to navigate to `/Admin/my.theme.name/Home/Profile` (Controller=Home, Action=Profile, Area=my.theme.name) instead of `/Admin/Users/Edit` (Controller=Admin, Action=Edit, Area=OrchardCore.Users).

`UserMenuItems-Profile.cshtml`

```html
@using System.Security.Claims

@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, CommonPermissions.EditOwnUser))
{
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="OrchardCore.Users" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-returnUrl="@FullRequestPath">
            <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> @T["Profile"]
        </a>
    </li>
}
else if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, CommonPermissions.ViewUsers))
{
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="OrchardCore.Users" asp-action="Display" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-id="@User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)" asp-route-returnUrl="@FullRequestPath">
            <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> @T["Profile"]
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

I have attempted to override the existing `UserMenuItems-Profile.cshtml` file (originally located in `src/OrchardCore.Modules/OrchardCore.Users/Views/UserMenuItems-Profile.cshtml`) by adding a new file to `my.theme.name/Views/OrchardCore.Users/UserMenuItems-Profile.cshtml`.

This however doesn't seem to work, both as a module and theme. The dropdown list remains the same no matter what.